# Optimized SELECT query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a very large number of rows in my table, `table_1`. Sometimes I just need to retrieve a particular row.

I assume, when I use SELECT query with WHERE clause, it loops through the very first row until it matches my requirement.

Is there any way to make the query jump to a particular row and then start from that row?

Example:

Suppose there are 50,000,000 rows and the id which I want to search for is 53750. What I need is: the search can start from 50000 so that it can save time for searching 49999 rows.

I don't know the exact term since I am not expert of SQL!

Comment: I think you need to make an index. With an clustered index on the id field your db engine will be able to go directly to the good record whithout looping.

Comment: Well, as I said I am not an expert, can you please elaborate it please?

Comment: http://hackmysql.com/case1

Comment: Why not have it start at 53750 and only cycle one? But all kidding aside, you need 1) get some extra knowledge on databases and 2) create an index. Good luck!

Comment: can you show you table schema?

Answer (score 3):

You need to create an index : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-index.html

```
ALTER TABLE_1 ADD UNIQUE INDEX (ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand it, you want to select a row with id 53750. If you have a field named id you could do this:

```
    SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE id = 53750
```

Along with indexing the id field. That's the fastest way to do so. As far as I know.

Comment: I believe OP wants to know how to start the query at a certain ID and then move upwards to find it (that is to say the id will be found at runtime), so I'm not sure your answer really helps in that regard.  However, the index will certainly make the situation better.

Comment: My fault. I've misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ALTER table_1 ADD UNIQUE INDEX (<collumn>)
```

Would be a great first step if it has not been generated automatically. You can also use:

```
 EXPLAIN <your query here>
```

To see which kind of query works best in this case. Note that if you want to change the where statement (anywhere in the future) but see a returning value in there it will be a good idea to put an index on that aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Create an index on the column you want to do the `SELECT` on:

```
CREATE INDEX index_1 ON table_1 (id);
```

Then, select the row just like you would before.

But also, please read up on databases, database design and optimization. Your question is full of false assumptions. Don't just copy and paste our answers verbatim. Get educated!

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to know about optimizing select queries like [Range](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/range-optimization.html) and [Where clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/where-optimizations.html) Optimization, the documentation is pretty informative baout this issue, read the section: [Optimizing SELECT Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-optimization.html). [Creating an index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) on the column you evaluate is very helpfull regarding performance too.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution You can create View then query from view. here is details of creating view and obtain data from view

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp

now you just split that huge number of rows into many view (i. e row 1-10000 in one view then 10001-20000 another view )

then query from view.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that any SQL database with a little respect for themselves does not start looping from the first row to get the desired row. But I am also not sure how they makes it work, so I can't give an exact answer.

You could check out what's in your WHERE-clause and how the table is indexed. Do you have a proper primary key? Like using a numeric data type for that. Do you have indexes on more columns, that is used in your queries?

There is also alot to concider when installing the database server, like where to put the data and log files, how much memory to give the server and setting the growth. There's a lot you can do to tune your server.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and split  your tables in [partitions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-overview.html)

[More about alter tables to add partitions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table-partition-operations.html)

[Selecting from a specific partition](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-selection.html)

In your case you could create a partition on ID for every 50.000 rows and when you want to skip the first 50.000 you just select from partition 2. How to do this ies explained quite well in the MySQL documentation.

Answer (score -1):

You may try simple as this one.

```
query = "SELECT * FROM tblname LIMIT 50000,0
```

i just tried it with phpmyadmin. WHERE the "50,000" is the starting row to look up.

EDIT : 
   But if i we're you i wouldn't use this one, because it will lapses the 1 - 49999 records to search.

Comment: And what if record with id 53750 is not after the 50,000th row, but before it? MySQL gives no guarantees on how records are stored.

Comment: As a i edit it, i wouldn't guarantee you to use that one. You may use binary search instead of linear search. Google it.

Comment: Or you let MySQL do the searching. It is quite good at it, if you have designed your database well.

Comment: Linear Search - http://scanftree.com/Data_Structure/Linear-search

Binary Search - http://algorithms.openmymind.net/search/binarysearch.html

It will reduce your time for searching for id if you use some array. Check the link.